# How count the frequency of occurence of each value in a column in Table "A" and insert in a Table "B" using SQLitein an android app

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have a simple app that contains an Sqlite database containing 2 tables:

`TABLE_CHAP` that contains:

- _id
- Chapter_title
- Number_of_flashcards

`TABLE_Flash` contains:

- _id
- Chap_id
- flashcard content

I upload the content of the database to the assets folder, `TABLE_FLASH` contains a number of flashcards that belongs to each chapter.
What I'm trying to do is to count the frequency of Chap_id in `TABLE_FLASH` and insert this number to Number_of_flashcards in `TABLE_CHAP` and afterward display the `number_of_flashcard` in front of the concerned `Chapter_Title`.
the `Number_of_flashcards` is dynamic as the user may add his own flashcards to each chapter.

```
public void nberOfFlahcards(){
    int xy= getChap_tableCount();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
     database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     for(int i=1; i<=xy; i++){

         String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_CHAP WHERE Chap_ID = " + i;              

             Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

             int total_count=cursor.getCount();

             Log.v(TAG, "Nber of Flashcards for chapter"+i+"is: "+total_count);



                contentValues.put(KEY_NBER_FLAHCARDS, Integer.toString(total_count));

                database.update(TABLE_CHAP,contentValues, KEY_NBER_FLAHCARDS,null );
```

this code gave me always 0, please check where's the error and if you have better code or better architecture for the database please advise.

Comment: Why not just run the count when you need it?  Why do you need to store it in the database?

Comment: Very Good suggestion, however I was asked for that.

Comment: You will then need triggers to maintain the value as records are inserted, deleted, and updated.

Answer (score 1):

This update can be done with a single query

```
UPDATE TABLE_CHAP  SET Number_of_flashcards = 
 (SELECT count(*)
    FROM TABLE_Flash AS tf
   WHERE tf.Chap_id=TABLE_CHAP._id)
```

But I'd better have a method `int getNumberOfFlashcards(int chap_id)` which computes the count for the given `chap_id`.

Comment: This does'nt worked for me, I think I need if you don't mind the full code. as it it doesn't recognized tc & tf